# RMagick dissolve tiled

Tags: imagemagick, rmagick

I have a picture of a paper, and I want to make it transparent, overlay it and tile it on top of another image.  However, dissolve won't tile it, and composite_tile won't make it transparent.  Any tips for how to do this?  Currently, I have

```
image = Magick::Image::from_blob(open(image_path).read)
image = image.composite_tiled(paper_texture_image)
```

However, this completely covers the image with paper so that you can only see the paper.  I want the paper to be see through and still tile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out.  You have to do something like this

```
paper_texture_image.opacity=0.5*QuantumRange
```

That will make a somewhat transparent texture.